# Linking both UIKit and AppKit

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I am trying to create a base object which can used on both the iPhone and OS X as a datasource. I would therefore have a header file with statements such as:

```
#ifdef TARGET_OS_IPHONE
#import <UIKit/UITableView.h>

@interface DataObject : NSObject<UITableViewDataSource>
#endif

#ifdef TARGET_OS_MAC
#import <AppKit/NSTableView.h>

@interface DataObject : NSObject<NSTableViewDataSource>

#endif
```

My current Xcode project is using a standard Apple iPhone template. My issue is when I select "Link Binary With Libraries" under the "Build Phases" tab I am only seeing iPhone related frameworks.

Of course I can select other and then browse, but I have no idea where AppKit.Framework lives. Can anyone point out where I can find this framework or how I can have a project link to both UIKit and AppKit

Comment: Use the finder to find the framework :-) It should be sufficient to search for AppKit.h.

Comment: Must be having an off day.

I found it in

/System/Library/Frameworks/Appkit.Framework

Answer (score 5):

Can I suggest a slightly different design?

Your `DataObject` should link against only Foundation, which exists on both iOS and Mac OS X.  It includes no methods for either of the data sources.

Then in your iOS app target, you have a category on DataObject that implements the UITableViewDataSource methods and in your OS X application target, you have a category on DataObject that implements the NSTableViewDataSource methods.

```
@interface DataObject(NSTableViewDataSource) <NSTableViewDataSource>
```

The user interface code in your iOS and OS X apps will be so different that you will need different targets anyway and they each link against the relevant SDK.